# storing values from table column to array in Python

Tags: python

I'm connecting access db and fetching values. In one of the column values are stored like

```
abc|def|ghi|xyz.
```

Need to replace `|` with space and store in array.

I'm trying below code but each character is stored in array like `"a b c ..."`

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
   names = row[1]
   names = names .replace("|", ",")

namesarray = []
namesarray = names

for fullname in (namesarray):
 --do something --
```

Comment: please print the output of row[1]

Comment: Maybe you want `names=names.split("|")` instead of replacing with comma?

Comment: Try `print("abc|def|ghi|xyz".split('|'))`

Comment: output of row[1] = abc|def|ghi|xyz

Comment: Thanks pault and Sagar. Split works.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`for row in cursor.fetchall(): 
    names = row[1] 
    names_arr = names.split('|')
print (names_arr)`